# Django i18n and python locales (and dates)

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I've been playing with Django's i18n system and it seems to be mostly working. However, dates in model code seem to be causing a problem.

I use datetime.strftime to populate a few CHOICES tuples which are then used in forms.

From what I understood, django will set the locale to the user's choice so that datetime.strftime() will output in the appropriate language, but this doesn't seem to happen.

What am I missing here?

If I set the locale manually (eg. locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME,'de_DE.UTF-8') ) datetime does translate correctly.

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django does not set locale for translation, just loads translation catalog. To get desired effect you have either set locale (which is not a good option since it works process-wide) or use specialized library. I recommend [Babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/) which has nice Django integration.

Comment: Ah, thank you zgoda. I rather think the django docs should be a little more explicit, they rather suggest that the i18n does more that it actually does.

Comment: I'd say it does "i18n" as advertized. Formatting dates and monetary values is "l10n" (localization) which is absent in Django anyways. That's the domain of Babel library. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've recently faced similar problem but managed to solve the problem by using [format](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/dateformat.py#L282) instead of the python `strftime`

Comment: I tried with format but %B and %b aren't recognized :( Any help ?

Comment: thank you code22 for the format solution, I didn't want to use babel for my small project. working as expected