# Language problem with date based generic views

Tags: django, django-urls, django-generic-views

I've changed the language-code from en-us to es-ar and the url's began to fail. 
Example: When I click in "Agosto 2010" the URL is "http://mysite.com/weblog/2010/**ago**/" and the server couldn't finde the page. But if I browse "http://mysite.com/weblog/2010/**aug**/ the server finds and shows the page.

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.date_based',
         (r'^$', 'archive_index', entry_info_dict, 'coltrane_entry_archive_index'),
         (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$', 'archive_year', entry_info_dict, 
  'coltrane_entry_archive_year'),
         (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/$', 'archive_month', entry_info_dict, 
  'coltrane_entry_archive_month'),
)
```

templatetags.py:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('coltrane/month_links_snippet.html')
def render_month_links():
    return {
        'dates': Entry.objects.dates('pub_date', 'month'),
    }
```

month_links_snippet.html:

```
<ul>
  {% for d in dates reversed %}
    <li><a href="/weblog/{{ d|date:"Y/b" }}/">{{ d|date:"F Y" }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`archive_month`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-date-based-archive-month) generic view takes a `month_format` parameter, which specifies a [`strftime`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime) directive (defaulting to `'%b'`, for the locale's abbreviated month name) to parse the `month` value with.

The problem is that `strftime` uses the process's POSIX [locale](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html), which is *not* set by Django's own locale mechanism (which is what the `date` template filter uses). See this earlier question:

- [Django i18n and python locales (and dates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318744/django-i18n-and-python-locales-and-dates)

You could fix this in one of two ways:

1. To keep using textual months, set Python's POSIX locale to match Django's `LANGUAGE_CODE`, for example by adding `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, LANGUAGE_CODE)` to your settings module. This should make `strptime` parse the same month abbreviations as produced by the `date` template filter. (**Note:** This assumes that you treat the installation's locale as static, and won't use something like `LocaleMiddleware` to change it dynamically.)
2. To switch to numeric months (01–12), make the following changes:

   - `archive_month` view: `(?P<month>\d{2})`, and add `month_format='%m'`
   - template: `{{ d|date:"Y/m" }}`